# The distribution of powers of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

How often do we see two or more powers of primes between two consecutive primes $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$?
One example is $p_4=7$ and $p_5=11$; we have
$$
7 < 2^3 < 3^2 < 11.
$$
Are there any other examples of this kind?

Comment: What? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. $1)$ It lacks being clear. $2)$ It displays no attempt of you answering the question independently. $3)$ It does not reveal your skill level in maths, so we cannot even make sure that you understand our answers.

Comment: @Alex  Thanks Alex, how could I not notice the elephant ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ denote a prime. We call the integer $p^a, \ a\in{\mathbb N},$ a *prime power*.

In the following, assume $a>1$. Prime powers with exponents $a>1$ are more rare than primes. It is not difficult to see that the vast majority of intervals $[p_k,p_{k+1}]$ do not contain any prime powers. Only a zero proportion of such intervals contain a prime power (even though there are infinitely many prime powers). Examples like 
$$7<2^3<3^2<11 \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad 
23<5^2<3^3<29,$$ 
with more than one prime power in a single interval $[p_k,p_{k+1}]$, are *extremely rare*.
Moreover, on probabilistic grounds we should expect that the total number of examples like this is finite. (I doubt that there is a rigorous proof of this. This result seems to be no easier than the [Mihailescu theorem a.k.a. Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_conjecture).)

**Some numerical data.** Among the first 10000 prime powers, there are only five examples:
$$
7 < 8=2^3 < 9=3^2 < 11 \\
23 < 25=5^2 < 27=3^3 < 29 \\
113 < 121=11^2 < 125=5^3 < 127 \\
2179 < 2187=3^7 < 2197=13^3 < 2203 \\
32749 < 32761=181^2 < 32768=2^{15} < 32771
$$

According to OEIS (https://oeis.org/A053706) there are no other examples for primes up to $2^{63}$. Thanks Matthew Conroy for pointing out the OEIS sequence!

Comment: Check http://oeis.org/A053706 has some info.